# why 220v power supply may damage a system working on 110 V?

Tags: power-supply

why 220v power supply may damage a system working on 110 V?

After some research I found out that 220 V is 50 HZ & 110 V is 60 HZ ...

Also I've a guess that the inner design of the 110 V system contains a transformer that steps down the voltage , so 220 V may be stepped down to a value bigger than the expected value .

Any scientific explanation ?

Edit#1:- 
 a PSU designed for 110 Vac being plugged into 220 Vac. why it damage ?

Can you provide an answer with circuit example ?

Comment: @Telaclavo I think he means the opposite: a PSU designed for 110 Vac being plugged into 220 Vac. But anyway, the question is confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most simple component must be the resistor. Power in a resistor is

\$ P = \dfrac{V^2}{R} \$

That means the power in the same resistor will be 4 times as big at 220V than at 110V. The resistor is not designed for that, will overheat and break. A number of components may fail this way.

Another failure method is due to insulation breakdown. Some components, like electrolytic capacitors have a thin insulation layer in them that's designed to withstand a certain voltage. Twice the rated voltage may cause the higher voltage to break through the insulation. That's what undoubtedly will happen in a PSU.

Want a circuit example?

[image]

If the transformer is a 110V/12V type the rectified voltage will be around 15V. Capacitor C1 may be a 20V type. Applying 220V will cause the transformer to get hotter, and after some time the insulation may break, and the fuse will blow due to the risen current. Too late, the transformer is gone. Long before that C1 will be gone. Applying 220V to the transformer will give you 24V out instead of 12V. Rectified that's 32V, much higher than the capacitor's rated voltage. It may explode with minutes. At 110V the 1k\$\Omega\$ resistor would dissipate 225mW. At 220V this becomes 1W. I know from experience that a 1/4W resistor can stand 1W for a very long time, so the resistor may be among the survivors, but it will have suffered damage as well.

Answer (score 10):

Scientific: why if you put an elephant in a shopping cart it breaks it?

#### Answer:

Because it's not made to carry an elephant

---

An appliance that works under 110 V will be designed to work at that voltage, not 220 V and not even 12 V DC. It may have a protection for dumb users, but it may not, and then it will break.

### Edit

The most likely effect is that things overheat, such as in steven's example. Another nasty situation is avalanche breakdown due to the too high reverse voltage of diodes:

[image]

link [here](http://www.circuitstoday.com/pn-junction-breakdown-characteristics). The diode blocks the current when reverse biased, but only until a certain voltage: then it starts conducing like a short circuit, much quickly than in direct connection, and the current will likely be destructive.

One of the risks is overheating, one is fried components, exploding capacitors, melting wires (add from fantasy)... It's really a competition on which component breaks first, which may have multiple winners.

Comment: I bet you never did the experiment. That's not scientific.

Comment: @stevenvh how can you say that? ;)

Comment: But what if it was a shopping cart for elephants?

Comment: @Dean impossible: everybody knows that elephants don't do shopping :)

Comment: @clabacchio - No, of course they don't go shopping, that would be ridiculous, and also they wouldn't be in the cart. But what if *you* go shopping for an elephant? Every now and then you need one. Our supermarket has carts for them.

Comment: @stevenvh *our supermarket has carts for them*: then it's a completely different story, because then they are elephant-rated

Comment: @clabacchio They may not go shopping, but they do stay at the Residence Inn by Marriott.

Comment: @CyberMen woooow too hard for me :)

Answer (score 3):

The single biggest reason that a transformer designed for use on 110 VAC will fail **VERY** rapidly when 200+ VAC is applied is because te transformer is designed to draw a certain "magnetising current": at the design voltage. This current is controlled mainly by the inductance of the windings at 110 V and whatever frequency it is designed for. This current is designed so that the metal in the transformer core is just starting to "saturate". Above this point the transformer fairly rapidly starts to turn into a low  value resistor.

When you apply double the voltage the windings attempt to draw double the voltage and apply twice the magnetising current BUT this drives the core heavily into saturation, the winding inductances fall to a low value and the current "avalanches".
 Magic smoke happens - maybe even magic flames and minor explosions if a suitable fuse is not equipped.

Answer (score 1):

1. The voltage is not related to the frequency: you can have 110V/50Hz, 110V/60Hz, 220V/50Hz, 220V/60 Hz. Check the "[Mains voltage by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country)" article on Wikipedia for a full list.
2. This happens because the device works on 110V: its components are designed for that. When you plug them into 220 V, those parts will be damaged since their design specifications are exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the OP's edit (why does a 110V power supply fail when plugged into 220V):

In addition to all the other damages that have already been discussed (transformers, downstream components getting overvoltage damage, etc.) consider this:

A power supply that's certified to operate at low-line only (meaning 90-130VAC) most likely will have a MOV across the mains that's rated for 135VAC. If you apply 220VAC, that MOV will hard-clamp the mains and unless the fuse goes quickly, it'll shatter quite spectacularly. Also, the fuse may not be rated at 250VAC, so once it opens there's no guarantee that it won't be bridged by the mains and continue to power the MOV.

Universal-input (85-264VAC) power supplies will typically use a 270VAC MOV and a 250VAC fuse. Once the fuse clears, you're "safe".

Also: if there's a configurable voltage-doubler on the front end (switches or jumpers that say either "110" or "220") and the switches are in the "110" position (the voltage doubler is in play), when 220 is applied, any bulk capacitors on the primary of the isolation transformer will not be rated for the much higher voltage that will be applied, and will loudly (and malodorously) pop due to having their maximum operating voltage exceeded by almost a factor of two.

Shall I go on? : )

Comment: "Universal-input (85-264VAC) power supplies". Those are a real problem. They will happily keep working, thus allowing the damage to go worse and worse.

Comment: @stevenvh It will cause damage only if it doesn't have a PFC preregulator (the DC/DC will typically see a fixed 400V input if there is one)

Comment: I was thinking of the 5V/2A wall warts I have here. They're switchers working at 90V to 250V. I don't think they have PFC. Or would they?

Comment: @stevenvh  Those tend to be wide-input flyback converters which cycle-skip at high input voltages and operate more continuously at low voltages. I was thinking of a cheap PC power supply where the operator can change the input range.